# Codeception not get data from child class

Tags: unit-testing, yii2, phpunit, yii2-advanced-app, codeception

I am working in Yii2 advance templete. I am writing a unit test using codeception
I have model common\models\Member. From member i inherit a child model superviser

Now i want to grab data from superviser Model but it give me empty array

```
 $model= $this->tester->grabRecord('common\models\Superviser ', array('member.id' => 8));
 print_r($model);
```

Thanks

Comment: You are saying that `Supervisor` class is a child of `Member` class. In that case `grabRecord(Superviser::class, ['id' => 8])'` should work.

Comment: If what you meant instead is that you have a 1-n relation between `Superviser` and `Member` then we probably need to specify what the relation looks like in your question, but, guessing that you have an attribute `member_id` in the `Superviser` class, it would be `['member_id' => 8)`

Comment: @RaulSauco why i specify member_id in child class. Supervioser is inherited from Member class

Comment: It seems like that is what you are trying to do by using `member.id` but that dot notation does not mean anything in an array key, so I was guessing that you were had a `member_id` attribute. If, like you say, `Superviser` inherits from `Member` it seems like you should be able to get the model by it's `id`.

Comment: Did you try `grabRecord(Superviser::class, ['id' => $id]`? GrabRecord works just like `ActiveRecord::findOne()` you can specify one or multiple conditions the same way you do in a [where](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#where()-detail).

Comment: @RaulSauco Thanks for solving my Problem. There is in issue in my data file. So now i am trying to fix it.

Comment: If that solved your problem I will turn the comment to an answer, feel free to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

#### You need to modify the name of the attribute that you are using in `grabRecord()`

You can think of `grabRecord()` like the test version of `ActiveRecord::find()` or `ActiveRecord::findOne()` the parameters you pass to the method will be used to construct the query that will get the record.

In your example you are using `member.id` with probably doesn't match any attributes on your `Superviser` class, you need to change that to the attribute you want to fetch by, in your case it seems to be `id`.

```
$I->grabRecord(Superviser::class, ['id' => $id]);
```

Should do the trick. To find more information on different ways to query for data you could check the `Yii` documentation for [queryinterface::Where()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#where()-detail)